# How to use ngModel two-way binding to bind some properties of one object to another object?

Tags: angular, ngmodel

Is is possible to bind some properties of one object to another object using two way binding in Angular? One example is like:

**JS**

```
object_1 {
    property1:string,
    property2:string,
    property3:string,
    property4:string
}

object_2 {
    property1:string,
    property2:string,
    property3:string
}

objects_1: object_1[];
objects_2: object_2[];
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let object1 of objects_1">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="object1.property1"> 
    <select [(ngModel)]="object1.property2+object1.property3+object1.property4">
        <option *ngFor="let object2 of objects_2" [ngValue]="object2">
        </option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no this is not possible since the value of the ngModel directive will be set as the selected option of the select element (in this case). So this must be a single property to bind to.

However if you want to assign the value of the selected option to multiple properties, you could use the ngModelChange eventEmitter to populate the values:

```
<select [ngModel]="object1.property2" (ngModelChange)="object1.property2 = $event; object1.property3 = $event; object1.property4 = $event"> ... </select>
```